# Break this Query into batches

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table **contacts**, with structure as follows

```
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| contactee_id | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| contacter_id | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

contactee_id and contacter_id are both ids, which together defines a relationship between two users. In order to calculate the count of relations, a user have, I have the following query

```
INSERT INTO followers (id, followers) 
   SELECT contactee_id, 1 
     FROM contacts 
     ON DUPLICATE KEY 
      UPDATE followers = followers + 1
```

The problem with this query is that it locks the *contacts* table for too long (more than 16 minutes). I want to get it done in batches, so that the SQL does not locks contacts table for too long. Few ways, I thought of, but they all need to lock the entire table. Is there a way this could be done?

Comment: How many rows does your contacts contain? How many followers? Can you post the execution plan of the insert?

Comment: Contacts table contains ~30m rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the count of relations use the count and group by together like

```
SELECT contactee_id,count(contacter_id) FROM contacts group by contactee_id;
```

This will give you all the contactee_id and the number of contacter_id's for each contactee

Comment: grouping will also lock the table.

Answer (score 0):

Run query for some records and then save the id of the last record in a table or filesystem, start next query from that id and update it every cycle.